# Capture specific text from output into a variable

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script that will detect what COM port a device is plugged into, then map it to a new port.

Here is the output from the "change port" command:

```
PS C:\> change port
COM11 = \Device\19H2KP0
COM2 = \Device\Serial1
COM5 = \Device\Serial2
KEYSPAN#*USA19HMAP#00_00#{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} = \Device\ComUs19H-00
KEYSPAN#*USA19HMAP#00_00#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73} = \Device\ComUs19H-00
USA19HP0 = \Device\19H2KP0
```

I need to capture the COM number prior to "\Device\19H2KP0". So in this example output, I would capture COM11 into a variable.

Next I need to run the "change port" command with that variable. i.e.:

```
change port COM1=$CapturedText
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Longer, but perhaps more intuitive, you can also use chained -match and -replace operators with simpler regexes:

```
$CapturedText = (change port) -match 'COM.+19h2kp0' -replace '^(COM\d+).+','$1'
$CapturedText
```

Comment: Hey thanks! This seems to work perfectly. Now I'm having an issue running the command: "change port COM1=COM7" from a variable. The text seems to execute just fine, but it doesn't actully run the DOS command "change port".  
  
`$ComNum = (change port) -match 'COM.+19h2kp0' -replace '^(COM\d+).+','$1'  
change port COM1=) + $ComNum  
$changeport`

Comment: Oops, the code got messed up.  `$ComNum = (change port) -match 'COM.+19h2kp0' -replace '^(COM\d+).+','$1'
$changeport = (change port COM1=) + $ComNum
$changeport`

Answer (score 1):

Do you already know what the `19H2KP0` bit will be? If so, you could use a regular expression to detect the unique ID using a look-ahead.

Here's a fully working example, using your example text:

```
$Output = @"
COM11 = \Device\19H2KP0
COM2 = \Device\Serial1
COM5 = \Device\Serial2
KEYSPAN#*USA19HMAP#00_00#{4d36e978-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318} = \Device\ComUs19H-00
KEYSPAN#*USA19HMAP#00_00#{86e0d1e0-8089-11d0-9ce4-08003e301f73} = \Device\ComUs19H-00
USA19HP0 = \Device\19H2KP0
"@

$Output -match "COM[0-9]{1,2}(?=.*$Id)";

Write-Host -Object ('COM port is: {0}' -f $matches[0]);
```

And now here is the example, using the in-line command:

```
$Id = '19H2KP0';
$Output = change port;
$Output -match "COM[0-9]{1,2}(?=.*$Id)";
Write-Host -Object ('COM port is: {0}' -f $matches[0]);
```

### Result

```
COM port is: COM11
```

Comment: So the script definetly detects the correct string based on the $Id, but I get the following error:   `COM7 = \Device\19H2KP0  
Cannot index into a null array.  
At line:4 char:1  
+ Write-Host -Object ('COM port is: {0}' -f $matches[0]);  
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: That error means that the `$matches` variable is not getting populated. The regular expression must not be working ... what is the output in the new example? Can you update your question with the new example?